# Разобрать одну строку кода

Tags: c++, математика, тернарный-оператор

Нужно разобрать строку `sum += (i / 2) ? i : 0;` как работает это условие и как его заменить через оператор `if`

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int n, sum = 0;
std::cin >> n;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = i +2)
{
    sum += (i / 2) ? i : 0;
}
std::cout << sum;
return (0);
}
```

Comment: В контекста данного цикла это - бессмысленное заведомо истинное условие. Заменяется на просто `sum += i`. Никакого `if` не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum += (i / 2) ? i : 0;
```

Прибавить к `sum`, если значение `i/2` ненулевое, число `i`, в противном случае - 0:

```
if (i/2) sum += i;
```

(поскольку в ветви `else` ничего не меняется - ее просто отбрасываем...)

Только вот смысла в этом - никакого. Так как для вашего цикла `i/2` всегда больше нуля - так что

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = i +2)
{
    sum += (i / 2) ? i : 0;
}
```

С легкостью переписывается как

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = i +2)
{
    sum += i;
}
```

Или еще проще, с учетом, что изначально `sum` равно 0:

```
sum = (n/2)*(1+n/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант попроще:

```
if (i > 1) sum += i;
```

но поскольку цикл начинается с двойки, то можно условие вообще не проверять.